# What does いいものの "ii mono no" mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> おやすみと言ったはいいものの、ついさっき気が付いてしまった私の中の恋心や、呑気にすうすうと寝息を立てるマヤの心の中が気になって眠気が全く感じられない.

I only understand "ii mono" as "good thing" so the beginning of this sentence isn't making much sense to me (also, not sure if the ending "no" is the explanatory "no", "koto" no, or possessive "no" particle, or something else).

Comment: Related; [The usage of ものの](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34182/43676), [Understanding the の in ～ものの](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13351/43676)

Comment: so, just wanna make sure i'm getting this right, is there a typo in the example sentence i provided above then? it seems like the closest construction to the expression in my question is とはいうものの (from the links you gave me to reference), so is the と[言った]はいいものの a typo? (the いい part should be いう)? Sorry, I'm just trying to understand if that いい is part of the expression construction or the いい for "good"?

it doesn't seem like the expression construction in my example sentence is explained by the " X からいい（ような）ものの Y " in the referenced link; i'm sure the answer is in that explanation somewhere

Comment: 「おやすみ」と言った（の）は　いい　[ものの](https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2018/04/13/jlptn2-grammar-monono/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ものの is yet another way to say "although". See the comment section. The part before comma is the same as おやすみと言ったはいいが or おやすみと言ったはいいけれども.

Then what does ～たはいいが mean? This is a set expression explained here: [「〜たはいいが、……」grammar pattern](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25955/5010)

So おやすみと言ったはいいものの means "I said good night (and things were fine until then), but...".